# Match substring with list members in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there any way in Big Query to use CONTAINS with a list of words, instead of one word at a time in a fashion like below:

SELECT
  page_title,
  IF (page_title CONTAINS **(SELECT sourceName FROM SOURCETYPES)**,1,0)
FROM VISITORS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using an equivalent JOIN?

```
SELECT word
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] a
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT SPLIT(fragments) fragment FROM (SELECT "duck,cat,bear" fragments)) b
WHERE word CONTAINS fragment
GROUP BY 1


word
---- 
bear     
scathful     
bearing  
dedication   
mollification    
...
```

*Replace "(SELECT SPLIT...)" with the desired "(SELECT sourceName FROM SOURCETYPES)".*